# How to fix error "CS7032 Key file 'myfile.snk' is missing the private key needed for signing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm using Intellitest for the first time on a project developed on VS2015.

As directed, I right click on my method name and choose 'Run Intellitest' from the menu.  This creates my test in a project, as expected, with a property and reference folder and the test file itself.

However, when I build it I get this error:

> Error   CS7032  Key file 'myFile.snk' is missing the private key needed
>   for signing

I know what the file with extension 'snk' is for but I don't know why I'm getting this error, especially when all I'm doing is building something Visual Studio created.  I've checked this file with other instances in other projects in the same solution which appear identical.  I don't know how to solve this.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

SNK files can come in two varieties.

1. The most common case is that it contains a public and a private key.
2. It can also only contain a public key. This seems to be your case.

When you have an SNK file that only contains a public key, you can must check the "Delay sign only" option under the your project's Properties->Signing tab.

Delay signing information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/delay-sign-assembly

In short, to truly sign an assembly you need the private and public keys. Delay signing places the public key into the assembly manifest as a placeholder. It should be overwritten later by an official signing process. This is often done by companies to allow developers to generate "signed" assemblies without distributing the official keys. A build lab/system that contains the official keys securely will build an official assembly and sign it with the company's official key.